# How to run a simple java client on Eclipse to communicate with a mobile server

Tags: java, android, eclipse, sockets, client

How can I run a simple Java client on Eclipse. I have written a small server code to run on an Android phone. It is supposed to receive strings from a PC client (running Java) and do some specific tasks accordingly. I have successfully tested my server code on Android, but I'm not sure how to configure Eclipse for running client side application. I'm using port 4444 for socket communication. How to make my client running on eclipse to listen to a specific port (4444).
I want to connect my PC client and Android phone over WiFi hotspot (simple communication based on private IP address). Please help!

Comment: If you know the IP of you phone and the port, just create a socket to connect to the server. Notice the client does not "listen", is the server which does that. The client just "requests" things to the server, so the client starts the communication and the server responds.

Comment: Thanks! Let me try once again. I'll keep you informed.

Answer (score 0):

The socket code is `new Socket("the ip address", 4444);`  If you are only writing strings, I would recommend attaching a `PrintWriter` to the socket's outputstream (and a scanner or BufferedReader for reading strings).